# "wired connection" doesn't show up

Tags: networking

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.
Before, I used to click on the two arrows in the top bar, and the correct "wired connection" use to show up in the menu.

But recently, the "wired connection" doesn't show up anymore when I click on the two arrows network icon. 
This is the case eventhough, /sbin/ifconfig and the connection are fine. eth0 get a dynamic IP address.

How can I get my "wired connection" back in the menu ?
Thank you.

-------------- EDIT

Previously, I thought it was because I introduced a HW firewall, but this is independant of this change

Comment: Why did you "set up a HW firewall between my modem and my machine"? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I am creating a subnet of machines. I don't expect a change on the "wired connection" showing up to occur when I click on the double arrow in the top bar of the screen. But no more "wired connection" show up.

Comment: What is the condition for "wired connection" to show up ? (showing up in /sbin/ifconfig is not sufficient it looks like. There are articles about installing WICD because of a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had this

```
user@machine:/etc/network$ more interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dns
```

If I remove this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dns
```

it works.